# Wordpress - how to show/hide content in page

Tags: php, wordpress

In Wordpress page text and other elements when added from admin, hidden for guests. When user is logged, private content showed for this user. This function created with plugin wp-private. I need get balance for user from other site api, if balance < n , should hide all content for logged users and showing other content . If balance > n , should show all content for logged users.  For this I used this code:

```
wp-content/themes/currentTheme/page.php:

<?php if(is_page("id_page")):

    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $balance = get_balance($user_id);
    if($balance <= 0){
      remove_post_type_support( 'post', 'editor' );
      echo "<a href='pay.php'>Pay</a>";
    }
  endif;

?>
```

After that still leaves the content page. What to do to not show page content?

Comment: Old thread, but would this be of any use? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/167132/hide-page-title